# Запись текста в формате UTF-8 в wstring

Tags: c++, строки, c++11

При записи строки символов кодировки UTF-8 в `wstring` каждый символ из кодировки записывается двумя символами (в примере снизу длина строки 12 вместо 6), из-за этого невозможно вывести конкретный символ. Пример кода

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    wstring str;
    getline(wcin, str);
    wcout << str << ' ' << str[0] << ' ' << str.length() << endl;
}
```

При вводе строки `Привет` выводит

> Привет � 12

При добавлении локализации (код снизу) перестает вопринимать русские буквы и оставляет строку пустой

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    wcin.imbue(locale("ru_RU.UTF-8"));
    wcout.imbue(locale("ru_RU.UTF-8"));

    wstring str;
    getline(wcin, str);
    wcout << str << ' ' << str[0] << ' ' << str.length() << endl;
}
```

Отключение синхронизации iostreams с stdio не помогает

ПС использую в CLion на OS X 10.10.5

ПСС при использовании `wchar_t*` и `printf/scanf` таких проблем нет

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в качестве исходной использовать `std::string`, а затем конвертируйте:

```
std::wstring to_wstr(const std::string& _str) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes(_str.c_str());
}
```

Comment: `<codecvt>` устарел в С++17